# Trying to avoid a for loop in r

Tags: r

I have some code that works but is very clunky and I'm sure there is a better way to do it, avoiding the for loop. Essentially I have a list of performances, and a list of factors. And I want to assign the highest performance to the highest factors, the lowest performance to the lowest factors, etc. Here is some simplified sample code:

```
#My simplified sample list of performances:

PerformanceList <- data.frame(v1 <- c(rep(10,4)), v2 <- c(rep(9,4)), v3 <- c(rep(8,4)))


View(PerformanceList)
v1                  v2                v3
1  10                  9                  8
2  10                  9                  8
3  10                  9                  8
4  10                  9                  8


#My simplified sample list of Factors:

MyFactors <- data.frame(v1 <- c(35,25,15,5), v2 <- c(10,20,60,20), v3 <- c(5,10,15,40))

View(MyFactors)
     v1                  v2                 v3
1    35                  10                  5
2    25                  20                  10
3    15                  60                  50
4    5                   20                  40


#Code to find the ranking of each row from largest to smallest:

Rankings <- data.frame(t(apply(-MyFactors, 1, rank, na.last="keep",ties.method="random")))

View(Rankings)
          v1          v2         v3
1         1           2           3
2         1           2           3
3         3           1           2
4         3           2           1
```

Function to sort each row by ranking. I assume there is a better way to do this but I couldn't figure it out:

```
 SortFunction <- function(RankingList){
 SortedRankings <- order(RankingList)
 return(SortedRankings)
 }

#applying that Sort function to each row of the data frame: 

SortedRankings <- data.frame(t(apply(Rankings, 1,SortFunction)))

View(SortedRankings)
    X1   X2   X3
1   1    2    3
2   1    2    3
3   2    3    1
4   3    2    1
```

Here is a for loop that does what I want but I'm sure it's not the best way to do it. Basically I want to go down each row of my PerformanceList and choose the column that corresponds to the highest Ranking (which is column 1 from my Sorted Rankings above). I'd ideally like to then be able to assign column 2 from those Sorted Rankings to assign the second highest performance to my second highest factor, and so on...

```
FactorPerformanceList <- data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol=1, nrow=NROW(Rankings)))
for (i in 1:NROW(Rankings)){
FactorPerformanceList[i,] <- PerformanceList[i,SortedRankings[i,1]]
}

View(FactorPerformanceList)
1     10
2     10
3      9
4      8
```

It seems like this should work but it gives a matrix of 4 rows by 4 columns instead:

```
FactorPerformanceList2 <- PerformanceList[,SortedRankings[,1]]

View(FactorPerformanceList2)
   v1     v1     v2      v3 
1  10     10      9       8
2  10     10      9       8
3  10     10      9       8
4  10     10      9       8
```

Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You've shown your attempts, but it is still unclear what you are after as a desired output. Do you want column or row positions, do you want to have both side by side?

Comment: You should use `=` rather than `<-` inside `data.frame`. Otherwise, the names can come out wrong and you'll be assigning vectors to the global environment in addition to adding them to the `data.frame`

Comment: A general comment: using one data frame to sort another is a recipe for confusion in R. It's best to keep everything in one data frame if you can.

Comment: Hi everyone, sorry my post wasn't clear. Basically I just want to be able to go down the data.frame Performance and use my list of SortedRankings to select which column to choose from each row. My for loop above gives the desired output, I just know there is a better way I could go about getting that same result. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Given the lack of clarity I've come up with a somewhat flexible answer for you.
It might make sense to take a given data.frame and force it to take a long format, we can make sure we maintain the index positions from the prior structure as this is what you might use to join other data.frames to one another.

I've chosen to use the `tidyverse` suite of packages to answer this, namely `dplyr`.

#### Data

```
library(tidyverse)
PerformanceList <- data.frame(v1 = c(rep(10,4)), v2 = c(rep(9,4)), v3 = c(rep(8,4)))
MyFactors <- data.frame(v1 = c(35,25,15,5), v2 = c(10,20,60,20), v3 = c(5,10,15,40))
```

This function will take a data.frame and provide a long format data.frame with index position columns.

#### Function to convert to long data.frame with index ranks

```
df_ranks <- function(df) {

  names(df) <- 1:ncol(df)
  df %>%
    mutate(row_index = 1:nrow(.)) %>%
    gather(col_index, value, -row_index) %>%
    group_by(row_index) %>%
    mutate(row_rank = rank(value, na.last = "keep", ties.method = "random")) %>%
    group_by(col_index) %>%
    mutate(col_rank = rank(value, na.last = "keep", ties.method = "random")) %>%
    ungroup()

}
```

Applying the function to the data, and making sure to adjust column names will let us join without much hassle.

```
ranked_perf <- df_ranks(PerformanceList) %>% setNames(paste0("rank_", names(.)))
ranked_fact <- df_ranks(MyFactors) %>% setNames(paste0("fact_", names(.)))
```

We can then join the tables, its important to understand what you want to do and what the expected result may be before this step. For this example I've said that I want to have the matching values within a column by its rank.

```
full_join(ranked_perf, ranked_fact,
          by = c("rank_col_rank" = "fact_col_rank",
                 "rank_col_index" = "fact_col_index"))
```

As to what you want to do with this result is up to you, you can select columns and manipulate it back to wide format using combinations of `select`, `unite`, and `spread`.

Comment: Thanks very much. As I just posted below, I'm having a problem getting the tidyverse package to load. This is the error message I'm getting. Have you ever run into this before? Thanks!               
                                                                                                      
 Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘psych’

Comment: No I haven't, maybe try installing what its telling you is missing, the psych package.

Comment: Thanks zac! Installing that psych package fixed my problem getting tidyverse to load. I'll take a look at your code. I'm sure it works but it's going to take me some time to wrap my head around the output (I'm new to R so it will be good for me to work through it). I need something that returns (10,10,9,8) as in my example above. I'm sure it's in the output I get with your code but I haven't figured out a good way to get it out yet.

Answer (score 0):

This technically does not *remove* the for-loop, it just hides it.  That said, it's a lot cleaner code than what you have, and unless you need all the intermediate data steps, it simplifies things greatly.

```
PerformanceList <- data.frame(
  v1= c(rep(10,4)), 
  v2= c(rep(9,4)), 
  v3 = c(rep(8,4))
  )
MyFactors <- data.frame(
  v1 = c(35,25,15,5),
  v2 = c(10,20,60,20), 
  v3 = c(5,10,15,40))


FactorPerformanceList <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(1:nrow(PerformanceList), function(i) {
  PerformanceList[i,order(MyFactors[i,])]
})))
```

The same code can be written

```
library(tidyverse)
FactorPerformanceList <- 1:nrow(PerformanceList) %>%
sapply(function(i) {
  PerformanceList[i,order(MyFactors[i,])]
}) %>%
t() %>%
as.data.frame()
```

which makes the order of operations a little clearer (`sapply`, then `t`, then `as.data.frame`).

In general, for-loops can be avoided completely when you're working with columns, but row-wise operations aren't as easy to remove entirely.  You can clean up the code by using the `apply` family of functions, or (if you want something fancier) the `plyr` or `purrr` packages.

Comment: Thanks very much. I tried to run this but I got an error message loading the tidyverse library. Have you ever run into this before?              
                                                                                                      
 Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘psych’

Comment: I haven't seen that before, but other people have had similar issues with other packages.  Try installing the psych package - thats what others seem to report working

Comment: Thanks Melissa! That fixed my problem installing the tidyverse package and I just tried your code and it does just what I need and is much simpler than what I had written.